# How to compare string to integer with while do loop in pascal?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

How to compare string to integer using while loop in Pascal?
Like this:

```
var Destination:string;
while (Destination>'11') do begin
    writeln('Error');
    write('Destination Number');
    readln(Destination);
end;
```

Comment: why don't you declare Destination as integer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `Destination` to an integer:

```
program Project1;

uses sysutils;

var
  converted: integer;
  Destination: string;

begin
  converted := 12;
  Destination := '';
  while (converted > 11) do
  begin
    writeln('Error');
    writeln('Destination Number');
    readln(Destination);
    converted := StrToIntDef(Destination, 12);
  end;
end.
```

convertion routines are avalaible in sysutils:

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/index-5.html

Comment: Yes it worked  it becomes error. But when I enter numbers less than 11 first it also says error. This is the output im trying to say:                                                 Current Destination Number: 5                                                              Error                                                                                               Current Destination Number:22                                                              Error                                                                                                  What to do again?? thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do the conversion in the WHILE--DO statement?

```
ReadLn(Destination);
WHILE StrToInt(Destination) > 11 DO NumberIsTooHigh;
```

where NumberIsTooHigh simply is a procedure you write to handle your "error". Ex:

```
PROCEDURE NumberIsTooHigh;
  BEGIN
    WriteLn('Your number is above valid range');
    write('Destination Number');
    readln(Destination);
  END;
```

The reason for the previous routine to make "error" on the first run is that "Destination" does not yet have a value at all. The converted-variable is then set manually to 12, just outside the Ok-range, hence it will always produce the error on startup.